# how to get a program to fill out a web page

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, html

I am trying to make an application that will fill in the info i type into the actual web page so I can register at websites very very easy whenever I need them. However I'm not sure how I would go about this. I know I would either have to use a WebBrowser or an Html request, but I am not sure what the basic syntax for it is. I could really use the help!

EDIT: I am trying to use Document.GetElementByID in order to do this. I don't want to use plugins to do this. I want to go a program.

Comment: Huh. You can create emails much _more_ easily without a web interface. SMTP is for email, HTTP is for websites

Comment: im not talking about just emails i meant registering to website in general

Comment: Hmm. Rereading the question, you simply need a good browser. I think most browsers will already do this, if you want (at least Opera can)

Comment: well I mean I want to be able to type in the fields for the registration form on a website in my program then press a button and it automatically registers for me so it's like an auto registration form type of thing

Comment: again, my browser does that (mostly). Also look at plugins like **[BugMeNot](http://www.bugmenot.com/)**

Comment: This feature comes out of the box with all recent releases of browsers as far as I'm aware (not sure about IE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into Browser Helper Objects and how to implement them in .NET. BHO-s can interact with the page loaded into an IE browser.